# how to print something on console from Antlr4 grammar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, antlr4

Actually i want to use a static java class in Antlr grammar, something like getting a value from that class and printing on console only using grammar. Is there a way to do it?
For example

```
parse
 : block EOF
 ;

block
: System.out.println(javaClass.getValue())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded code are called "actions" in ANTLR: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexicon.md#actions

In other words, do something like this:

```
grammar T;

@header {
  // Code will be placed outside the parser class
  static class JavaClass {
    public String getValue() {
      return "TODO";
    }
  }
}

@members {
  // Code will be placed inside the parser class
  private final JavaClass javaClass = new JavaClass();
}

parse
 : block EOF
 ;

block
 : stat+ {System.out.println(javaClass.getValue());}
 ;

stat
 : ...
 ;
```